# Multiplicative design matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression

In R, is

`model.matrix(~ Treatment + Time + Treatment*Time, table_design)`

equivalent to

`model.matrix(~ Treatment*Time, table_design)`

Comment: From help(formula): `The ‘*’ operator denotes factor crossing:  ‘a*b’ interpreted as ‘a+b+a:b’`. Note if you want to multiply covariates numerically, use `y~I(x1*x2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
table_design<-data.frame(
    Treatment=rep(c("A","B"), each=10),
    Time=rpois(20,20)
)
all.equal(
  model.matrix(~ Treatment + Time + Treatment*Time, table_design), 
  model.matrix(~ Treatment*Time, table_design)
)
# [1] TRUE
```